# Reading data from usb using ffs

Tags: c, linux, usb, gadgetfs, functionfs

I’m facing a problem where I’m unable to reliably read data from my usb endpoints. My ffs defines the following eps:

```
Ep0 = control
Ep1 = in
Ep2 = out
```

I have a simple `::read()` call that is blocked on int fd = ::open(ep1, O_RDONLY). Problem is that executing `::close()` on Ep1 has no effect on the ::read call and I’m pretty much blocked forever. I tried to apply select and poll Ep1 but these returned immediately even though no actual data was present on the end point, I later on also tried to apply the poll() and `select()` methods on Ep0 but those hanged indefinitely even though I tried to submit data with WinUSB which also hanged up. I must be missing something… not sure what

Edit:

```
  int fd_control_ = ::open("/dev/usb-ffs/ABC/ep0", O_RDWR);
  int fd_read = ::open("/dev/usb-ffs/ABC/ep1", O_RDWR);

  pollfd fd;
  fd.events = POLLIN|POLLOUT;
  fd.fd = fd_control_;

  int ret = poll(&fd, 1, -1) // this never returns

  return ::read(fd_read_, buffer, bufferSize); // without the poll, ::close never release ::read()
```

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. Could you provode a [mcve]?

Comment: WinUSB is only for Windows, so are you actually running Windows or Linux?  Maybe you can set the file descriptor to be in non-blocking mode before you do the read.

Comment: For the discussion Linux and writing to Ep2 using echo “xxx” > ep1

Comment: @hyde I added the post